# How to prevent menu from showing on mouse hover in this menu , and enable it to show only on mouse click?

Tags: css

I downloaded the sm-blue menu from a site ( which I forgot the address , sorry ). By default it shows the submenu on mouse hover and mouse click. I want it to show the submenu only on mouse click. Here are codes :

example of an application menu :

```
<ul class="sm sm-blue pull-left" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript.void(0);">Menu title</a>
        <li><a href="some_url">Sub menu</a></li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The sm-blue css :

```
@import url("googlefont.css");
.sm-blue {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -ms-border-radius: 8px;
  -o-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.sm-blue a, .sm-blue a:hover, .sm-blue a:focus, .sm-blue a:active {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  /* make room for the toggle button (sub indicator) */
  padding-right: 58px;
  background: #3092c0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #3298c8), color-stop(100%, #2e8cb8));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
  color: white;
  font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", "Arial Narrow", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  line-height: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.sm-blue a.current {
  background: #006892;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #006188), color-stop(100%, #006f9c));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
  color: white;
}
.sm-blue a.disabled {
  color: #a1d1e8;
}
.sm-blue a span.sub-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: auto;
  right: 4px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: bold 16px/34px monospace !important;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.sm-blue a.highlighted span.sub-arrow:before {
  display: block;
  content: '-';
}
.sm-blue > li:first-child > a, .sm-blue > li:first-child > :not(ul) a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  -o-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
.sm-blue > li:last-child > a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul,
.sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul,
.sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul,
.sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul,
.sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  -ms-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  -o-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}
.sm-blue > li:last-child > a.highlighted, .sm-blue > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a.highlighted,
.sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a.highlighted, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a.highlighted,
.sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a.highlighted, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a.highlighted,
.sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a.highlighted, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a.highlighted,
.sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a.highlighted, .sm-blue > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > *:not(ul) a.highlighted {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.sm-blue ul {
  background: white;
}
.sm-blue ul ul {
  background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.1);
}
.sm-blue ul a, .sm-blue ul a:hover, .sm-blue ul a:focus, .sm-blue ul a:active {
  background: transparent;
  color: #2b82ac;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-shadow: none;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
.sm-blue ul a.current {
  background: #006892;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #006188), color-stop(100%, #006f9c));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
  color: white;
}
.sm-blue ul a.disabled {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}
.sm-blue ul ul a,
.sm-blue ul ul a:hover,
.sm-blue ul ul a:focus,
.sm-blue ul ul a:active {
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
}
.sm-blue ul ul ul a,
.sm-blue ul ul ul a:hover,
.sm-blue ul ul ul a:focus,
.sm-blue ul ul ul a:active {
  border-left: 24px solid transparent;
}
.sm-blue ul ul ul ul a,
.sm-blue ul ul ul ul a:hover,
.sm-blue ul ul ul ul a:focus,
.sm-blue ul ul ul ul a:active {
  border-left: 32px solid transparent;
}
.sm-blue ul ul ul ul ul a,
.sm-blue ul ul ul ul ul a:hover,
.sm-blue ul ul ul ul ul a:focus,
.sm-blue ul ul ul ul ul a:active {
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
.sm-blue ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.sm-blue ul li:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Switch to desktop layout
  -----------------------------------------------
     These transform the menu tree from
     collapsible to desktop (navbar + dropdowns)
  -----------------------------------------------*/
  /* start... (it's not recommended editing these rules) */
  .sm-blue ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 12em;
  }

  .sm-blue li {
    float: left;
  }

  .sm-blue.sm-rtl li {
    float: right;
  }

  .sm-blue ul li, .sm-blue.sm-rtl ul li, .sm-blue.sm-vertical li {
    float: none;
  }

  .sm-blue a {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .sm-blue ul a, .sm-blue.sm-vertical a {
    white-space: normal;
  }

  .sm-blue .sm-nowrap > li > a, .sm-blue .sm-nowrap > li > :not(ul) a {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  /* ...end */
  .sm-blue {
    background: #3092c0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #3298c8), color-stop(100%, #2e8cb8));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px;
    -o-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .sm-blue a, .sm-blue a:hover, .sm-blue a:focus, .sm-blue a:active, .sm-blue a.highlighted {
    padding: 13px 24px;
    background: #3092c0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #3298c8), color-stop(100%, #2e8cb8));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    /*background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c8dbc, #3c8dbc);
    color: white;
  }
  .sm-blue a:hover, .sm-blue a:focus, .sm-blue a:active, .sm-blue a.highlighted {
    background: #2b82ac;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #2d89b4), color-stop(100%, #297ca3));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d89b4, #297ca3);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d89b4, #297ca3);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d89b4, #297ca3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d89b4, #297ca3);
  }
  .sm-blue a.current {
    background: #006892;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #006188), color-stop(100%, #006f9c));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
    color: white;
  }
  .sm-blue a.disabled {
    background: #3092c0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #3298c8), color-stop(100%, #2e8cb8));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    color: #a1d1e8;
  }
  .sm-blue a span.sub-arrow {
    top: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    bottom: 30%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    right: 5%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid dashed dashed dashed;
    border-color: #a1d1e8 transparent transparent transparent;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .sm-blue a.highlighted span.sub-arrow:before {
    display: none;
  }
  .sm-blue > li:first-child > a, .sm-blue > li:first-child > :not(ul) a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    -o-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  }
  .sm-blue > li:last-child > a, .sm-blue > li:last-child > :not(ul) a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0 !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0 !important;
    -o-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0 !important;
  }
  .sm-blue > li {
    border-left: 1px solid #2b82ac;
  }
  .sm-blue > li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
  }
  .sm-blue ul {
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
    padding: 7px 0;
    background: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .sm-blue ul ul {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: white;
  }
  .sm-blue ul a, .sm-blue ul a:hover, .sm-blue ul a:focus, .sm-blue ul a:active, .sm-blue ul a.highlighted {
    border: 0 !important;
    padding: 9px 23px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #2b82ac;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -o-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
  }
  .sm-blue ul a:hover, .sm-blue ul a:focus, .sm-blue ul a:active, .sm-blue ul a.highlighted {
    background: #3092c0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #3298c8), color-stop(100%, #2e8cb8));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3298c8, #2e8cb8);
    color: white;
  }
  .sm-blue ul a.current {
    background: #006892;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, to bottom, to top, color-stop(0%, #006188), color-stop(100%, #006f9c));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006188, #006f9c);
    color: white;
  }
  .sm-blue ul a.disabled {
    background: white;
    color: #b3b3b3;
  }
  .sm-blue ul a span.sub-arrow {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    right: 10px;
    border-style: dashed dashed dashed solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #a1d1e8;
  }
  .sm-blue ul li {
    border: 0;
  }
  .sm-blue span.scroll-up,
  .sm-blue span.scroll-down {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    height: 20px;
  }
  .sm-blue span.scroll-up-arrow, .sm-blue span.scroll-down-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-width: 8px;
    border-style: dashed dashed solid dashed;
    border-color: transparent transparent #2b82ac transparent;
  }
  .sm-blue span.scroll-down-arrow {
    top: 6px;
    border-style: solid dashed dashed dashed;
    border-color: #2b82ac transparent transparent transparent;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-rtl.sm-vertical a span.sub-arrow {
    right: auto;
    left: 10px;
    border-style: dashed solid dashed dashed;
    border-color: transparent #a1d1e8 transparent transparent;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-rtl > li:first-child > a, .sm-blue.sm-rtl > li:first-child > :not(ul) a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-rtl > li:last-child > a, .sm-blue.sm-rtl > li:last-child > :not(ul) a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px !important;
    -o-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px !important;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px !important;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-rtl > li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #2b82ac;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-rtl > li:last-child {
    border-left: 0;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-rtl ul a span.sub-arrow {
    right: auto;
    left: 10px;
    border-style: dashed solid dashed dashed;
    border-color: transparent #a1d1e8 transparent transparent;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-vertical {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-vertical a {
    padding: 9px 23px;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-vertical a span.sub-arrow {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    right: 10px;
    border-style: dashed dashed dashed solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #a1d1e8;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-vertical > li:first-child > a, .sm-blue.sm-vertical > li:first-child > :not(ul) a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    -o-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-vertical > li:last-child > a, .sm-blue.sm-vertical > li:last-child > :not(ul) a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px !important;
    -o-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px !important;
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px !important;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-vertical > li {
    border-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-vertical ul {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px !important;
    -o-border-radius: 4px !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
  }
  .sm-blue.sm-vertical ul a {
    padding: 9px 23px;
  }
}
```

So how to prevent the submenu from showing on hover in this case ?

Comment: your title contradicts your description, what exactly do you want?.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't replicate the behavior you described http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWVmqN Please give us a [mcve] of what you have currently that you're trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [SmartMenu](https://www.smartmenus.org/) plugin for jQuery, actually sm-blue is a theme class.

First, I think your structure is not well formed. you cannot nest li under li. It should be:

```html
<ul class="sm sm-blue pull-left" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript.void(0);">Menu title</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="some_url">Sub menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Anyway, I guess they provide noMouseOver option, just set it to true when initializing the script.

Or you can do it manually by implementing JavaScript handler as css cannot detect click even. First disable default css :hover behavior by changing the display property. Then you may use something like this (jQuery):

```js
$('.sm>li').click(function(){
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Or

```js
$('.sm>li').click(function(){
  
  if($(this).find('ul').hasClass('open')){
    $(this).find('ul').removeClass('open');
  } else {
    $(this).find('ul').addClass('open');
  }
  
});
```

Where class `open` should be defined in your css with display:block property, and the sub menu by default should have display:none property.

There is several way to achieve this through [jQuery](https://www.google.ps/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=jquery%20show%20submenu%20on%20click&*)